# How to fix error related to geocode reverse address for cross roads?

Tags: android, google-maps

Sorry if my questions looks silly, but I'm new on developing and on android. I wrote a snippet where I want to display a Google Map and to get the current location or a location selected by the user. But the address displayed with Geocoder is not very accurate, in special at the crossroads. Can you advise me how to solve the problem? Any observation regarding my code quality will be also very appreciated.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ReturnVehicleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

MapsActivity.java


package m.example.mapapp2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceDetectionClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    // private Location mylocation;
    private double longitude = 0;
    private double latitude = 0;
    //public double currentLongLocation = 0;
    //public double currentLatLocation = 0;
    private String address;

    private Location mylocation;

    //Buttons
    private ImageButton buttonSave;
    private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
    private ImageButton buttonView;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private PlaceDetectionClient mPlaceDetectionClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
        buttonSave = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
        buttonView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initialize the FusedLocationClient.
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
                this);


        // Initialize the PlaceDetectionClient.
        mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this, null);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //Setting the level of zoom
        float zoom = 10;
        //Initializing our map
        mMap = googleMap;
        //Creating a random coordinate
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(43.000000, 23.000000);
        //Adding marker to that coordinate
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
        //Setting onMarkerDragListener to track the marker drag
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        //Adding a long click listener to the map
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
       Toast messageToast = Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Connexion Failed",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Clearing all the markers
        mMap.clear();

        String snippet = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "Lat: %1$.5f, Long: %2$.5f",
                latLng.latitude,
                latLng.longitude);

        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position we are also making the draggable true
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true)
                .snippet(snippet));

        latitude = latLng.latitude;
        longitude = latLng.longitude;

        address = getAddress(MapsActivity.this, latitude, longitude);

        Toast addressMessage = Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        addressMessage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //Getting the coordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonCurrent) {
            getCurrentLocation();
            moveMap();
        } else {
            if (v == buttonSave) {
                Intent returnVehicleIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ReturnVehicleActivity.class);
                startActivity(returnVehicleIntent);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        } else {

            mMap.clear();

            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            if (location != null) {
                                mylocation = location;

                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();

                                address = getAddress(MapsActivity.this, latitude, longitude);

                                Toast addressMesage = Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                addressMesage.show();

                                moveMap();
                            } else {
                                Toast testsMesagge = Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "No location available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                testsMesagge.show();
                            }
                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION:
                // If the permission is granted, get the location,
                // otherwise, show a Toast
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getCurrentLocation();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            R.string.location_permission_denied,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {
        //String to display current latitude and longitude
        String msg = latitude + ", " + longitude;

        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Creating the snippet that will be displayed in marker
        String snippet = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "Lat: %1$.5f, Long: %2$.5f",
                latLng.latitude,
                latLng.longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .title("Current Location")  //Adding a title
                .snippet(snippet)); //Adding a snippet

        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    public String getAddress(Context context, double lat, double lng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Address obj = addresses.get(0);

            String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
            add = add + "," + obj.getAdminArea();
            add = add + "," + obj.getCountryName();

            return add;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of accuracy, it's completely dependant on the `LatLng` you are getting.

So you can check for the accuracy of the `LatLng` you are getting using `getAccuracy()` and request the `LatLng` again if the accuracy is poor.

For the code consistency, you need to check whether the Google Play Services are up to date, available or not and whether it's support on the target device.

I hope this answer your question and I can help you if you need anything.